# MIME error when uploading with PHP - docx files

Tags: php, file-upload

A website I am building allows file uploads by authorised users.  For any specific category of uploads, a set of file types is allowed, e.g. .pdf and .docx, so that my client can choose what they want to accept.

When uploading, I check the uploaded file's MIME type (using `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)`) against a database table of MIME types for that extension.

In testing, I am uploading a docx file from my PC - it has a docx extension and Windows reports the file type as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document which is what I expect.  However, `finfo_open` is giving me a MIME type of application/msword.

Does finfo_open's information come from within the file or from something in the browser or the upload process (in which case I guess I'll need to specify additional MIME types allowed) or is it something within the web server (in which case, can it be modified with php.ini)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in PHP it's safer to use the [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) to check out to file MIME type.

Still, I don't think it bothers for this. Are you sure you gave a `docx` and not just a `doc` document? Usually `application/msword` is the mime type for `doc` file extension... Make sure that you save your file using the right version of microsoft word and in the right format and then try again. Also, I'd try to use a `print_r` on `$_FILES` to see if what it tells you about the file? Does it tells you that the file has a different mime type?